# How to use the Vegas visualization within a scala-spark jupyter notebook

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, vega, vega-lite, vegas-viz

When using the `scala` kernel with `Vegas` we see the nice charts

[image]

But when switching to the `scala-spark` kernel the imports no longer work:

[image]

What is the way to fix the imports for the `spark` kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/254#issuecomment-238770728) you'll probably need to tweak your notebook config to pre-load those libraries, so they are available at runtime.

Then you can do a normal import (without the funny `$ivy` syntax, which actually comes from Ammonite REPL).

Comment: Actually what you pointed to was `addJar` - which btw I had found already to be working.  Where did you see "tweak notebook config" in that reference?

Comment: @javadba In theory you could add a jupyter kernel config, as described in the [docs](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernel-specs), so that yo don't have to type that in everytime you run the notebook.